# Authorization header value returns undefined in SuperTest

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, sails.js

So I am writing tests using Mocha, Supertest and Chai. All my API's require an `Authorization` header which can be gotten from `req.headers["authorization"]`. This is the current setup of what my test looks like.

```
...
describe("Upload media files", () => {
  it("uploads a file successfully", async () => {
    const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, "../../fixtures/profile.jpeg");
    const res = await app.post("/api/v1/account/upload") //app is global
      .set("Authorization", "ey83hfjksksls...") //right here
      .set("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
      .attach("media", imagePath);
    expect(res.status).to.eql(200);
    expect(res.body.data).not.to.be.null;
    expect(res.body.data).to.match(/https:/);
  });
});
```

My tests always fail because a `401` is always returned for some reason that I do not know. Here's the function that handle's the decoding of the JWT

```
async function decodeToken() {
 const sessionUser = req.session.userId;
    const token = req.headers["authorization"] // token value is present here.

    if (!token && !sessionUser) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: "Access denied, no valid credentials.",
      });
    }

    if (token) {
      const secret = sails.config.custom.jwtSecret || process.env.JWT_SECRET;
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret);
      req.me = decoded;
      return proceed();
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({
      id: sessionUser,
    });

    req.me = user;
    return proceed();
}
```

From the function above, when I do a console.log of the `token` variable, I do get a long string returned which shows that the token is being generated and passed into the `.set('Authorization', 'eyeur9339..')` header, but the test still fails. I don't know what to do anymore. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `jwt` for authorization, use `Bearer` before token so you should write Bearer, like this :

```
Bearer 5d5bd7f7e35a86541686f96c9cdd72ed67f5ba223811634e0319af224164823edc2d0090d1f6c2c3b1dec842ea783c71feb443ac2d26e
```

and for get token from header do like this :

```
const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, secret)
```